# Writing Nokogiri output to a text file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm very new to ruby. I understand how to read/write files(or so I thought), but I threw nokogiri into the mix and its got me scratching my head.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = "URL"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

crawl = page.css('.homehlcpm1 > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth- child(1)','.homehlcpm1 > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2)','.homehlcpm1 > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3)').each do |el|
puts el.text
puts
end
```

So, everything is currently working. Now when I try to write a file using "crawl" as my source I get a blank text document.

```
open("crawling.text", "w"){ |file| file.write(crawl)}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the script in a Unix environment you can redirect the script output to a file like this:

```
$ script_name.rb > crawling.txt
```

This way, every output (`p`, `puts`, `print`, etc.) from your script will be written in the file. 
Be aware that this is going to overwrite the file contents with the output of your script. If you want to just append the output to a file use this:

```
$ script_name.rb >> crawling.txt
```